# How to find the product of paths in a matrix from top-left to bottom-right in less than exponential time complexity?

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

How to efficiently find the product of paths to reach mat[r-1][c-1] from mat[0][0] if we can **ONLY** move rightwards or downwards? **1<= r, c <= 10^3.**
For example if the matrix is r=3, c=3.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

One possible path is 1->2->5->8->9 and product = 1*2*5*8*9 = 720.

Comment: Minimizing the product is equivalent to minimize the sum of the logarithms. Many algorithms exist fo finding the shortest path (sum) in a graph. In practice, i don't think you need to calculate the logarithms. Just adapt existing methods

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by `product of paths`?

Comment: @MBo By product of paths I mean the the product of integers that are present on the indices included in that path.In above example, one of the paths is (0,0)->(0,1)->(1,1)->(2,1)->(2,2).So, the product is mat[0][0]*mat[0][1]*mat[1][1]*mat[2][1]*mat[2][2] = 720.

Comment: @Damien But I don't need the shortest path. Actually, I want to check if the "product of a possible path" is divisible by a given integer 'k' or not. And count only such possible paths.

Comment: I don't understand. Product of single path? What one? Products of all possiple paths? Something else?

Comment: Consider the (`MxN`) matrix as a 2D lattice fragment and find all monotonic paths from `(1,1)` to `(M,N)`. Map each path to the product of matrix elements on that path. Find a  path whose product under this map is divisible by `k`.

Comment: @MBo I'm looking for products of possible paths **separately** and then how many of these products are divisible by an integer k.

Comment: @Touqueer Compute the 'path products' modulo `k` along each path you follow and you do not need a separate step to check divisibility: as soon as you run into a partial product of `0`, you are done.

Comment: @collapsar Thanks, but this is also taking more time (m*n)^2 operations (right?). As the constraints are 1<=r,c<=10^3 , How can optimize this using DP?

Comment: @collapsar Can you help optimizing the following code ?`bool countPath(int r, int c, unsigned long long prod) {
    bool l ,u;
 if (r < 0 || c < 0) {
  return false;
 }
 unsigned long long curProd = prod * a[r][c];
 if (((prod%K)*(a[r][c]%K))%K  == 0) {
  return false;
 }
 if (r == 0 && c == 0) {
  ans = (ans + 1) % MOD;
  return true;
 }
 l =countPath(r, c - 1, curProd);
 u =countPath(r - 1, c, curProd);
 return (l || u);
}`

Comment: @Touqueer I might, but I won't optimize on code level, sorry. I have too limited a knowledge of c++ and its library ecosystem to help you out here. If you are after optimization of a given code base and do not intend to abandon it altogether (eg. in favor of a completely different algorithm), then maybe the code review site would be a more suitable venue for your question anyway.

Comment: @collapsar I understand, actually I'm new here. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Touqeer Pathan But your question says nothing about divisibility by k and counting such paths. It is worth to edit the question, adding full problem statement

Answer (score 1):

The number of paths for a `MxN` matrix is

```
 / (M-1) + (N-1) \      / (M-1) + (N-1) \
|                 | =  |                 |
 \     M-1       /      \     N-1       /
```

For an accessible treatise have a look at one of the numerous web resources devoted to the problem, eg. [this one](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-combinatorics-number-of-paths-on-a-grid-bddf08e28384).

The basic intuition is that the number of vertical and horizontal movements is fixed across all paths, so the problem can be reduced to counting permutations.

For square `NxN` matrices the number of paths is the `N`-th Catalan number

```
       / 2 N \     / 2 N \
C_N = |       | - |       |
       \  N  /     \ N+1 /
```

(see eg. the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)).

In any case that means that the number of products is exponential in `N`, so efficiency will be limited.

If you are interested in an optimal path according to some criteria, the problem might allow for dynamic programming and thus polynomial space and time.